# Что означают заданные значения в куки?

Tags: cookie

Что означают заданные значения в куки?
а именно первые 6
[image]

**UPD**
Первые 6 - куки счетчиков.
Как работают эти счетчики, для чего ему нужны столько кук

Comment: Куки -- это именованные строковые переменные. Никакой предписанной семантики у имён переменных и их значений нет. Автор сайта может выбрать любое имя и любое значение. В переменной `sessionid` имеет право храниться, например, последняя дата логина или количество покупок.

Answer (score 1):

Первые 6 - куки счетчиков.

Последние 2 - токен и ид сессии.

Comment: как работают эти счетчики, для чего ему нужны столько кук

Comment: [Google Analitics пользуется в основном четырьмя сортами печенья...](http://habrahabr.ru/post/100212/)

`_ym_visorc` - это [Яндекс.Метрика](http://metrika.yandex.ru/promo/webvisor/)